# How to duplicate matrix rows in Torch

Tags: matrix, lua, torch

With Torch, how would I turn this matrix:

```
[1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9]
```

Into this:

```
[1 2 3
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 4 5 6
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
 7 8 9
 7 8 9]
```

?

In Matlab I would do it something like this:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
rows = repmat(1:size(a, 1), 1, 3);
b = a(rows(:), :);
```

Is there a similar method in Torch?

Answer (score 1):

This works ok:

```
a = a:repeatTensor(1, 3):reshape(9, 3)
```